# unable to install python-sdk for facebook

Tags: python, facebook

I'm not able to install python-sdk for facebook on Linux Mint. When I do:

```
pip install facebook-sdk
```

or

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk.git#egg=facebook-sdk
```

or
`pip install fb`     - terminal shows me :Success,
but I'm not able to 
import facebook in my project. Pycharm doesn't see it

Answer (score 0):

there are namy solutions to your problem

1. lets get to first one

*goto pycharm settings and go to project /project interpretor and do as the screenshot says*
[image: first part of screenshot ,here click on + sign]
*first part of screenshot ,here click on + sign*

[image]

type fb or anypackage related to it you want to install click apply and you are done